# UI-Performance for ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, performance

I know that Grails and Asp.net cannot be directly compared but still, does anyone know if there's something available for ASP.net that even remote resembles the functionality of the [UI-Performance Plugin for Grails](http://grails.org/plugin/ui-performance)?

Comment: What have you found by searching the web? And how doesn't it fit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do all this explicitly yourself. Very cool plugin though.

Anyway:

Move your own JS to the bottom of the page
Minify that stuff using an msbuild task  The [MSBuildCommunityTasks Project](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) has a few MSBuild tasks that may do what you are looking for including Merge and JSCompress.
Use YSlow with Firebug to track your score agains the Yahoo UI guidelines.

[Script Minification and Continuous Integration with MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278890/script-minification-and-continuous-integration-with-msbuild)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Aptimize - http://www.aptimize.com/ - costs money but does the same sort of thing